# Eclipse and PyDev using python from OSGeo4W

Tags: python-2.7, osgeo4w, eclipse, pydev

I'm trying to setup a PyDev Python Interpreter from OSGeo4W in Eclipse (neon 3 and java 8 on Windows 7 x64). I have installed the latest python 2.7.5 and python 3.6.? from OSGeo4W. I would like to avoid polluting the system environment variables in order to run different versions of python.

1. I click `New` under "Pydev/Interpreters/Python Interpreter".
2. I select C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python.exe.
3. I click OK and pydev tries to check if the selected python executable is okay.

Of course this doesn't work, since I haven't set up any environment variables. The error message is:

> ImportError: No module named site

But how can I avoid setting up environment variables outside Eclipse and just point at the OSGeo4W setup within Eclipse?

---

*Using the current state of python 3 from OSGeo4W doesn't seem to work, since it tries to use python 2.7 files.*